# Efficient way to check if std::string has only spaces

Tags: c++, string, optimization, whitespace

I was just talking with a friend about what would be the most efficient way to check if a std::string has only spaces. He needs to do this on an embedded project he is working on and apparently this kind of optimization matters to him.

I've came up with the following code, it uses `strtok()`.

```
bool has_only_spaces(std::string& str)
{
    char* token = strtok(const_cast<char*>(str.c_str()), " ");

    while (token != NULL)
    {   
        if (*token != ' ')
        {   
            return true;
        }   
    }   
    return false;
}
```

I'm looking for feedback on this code and more efficient ways to perform this task are also welcome.

Comment: `strtok(const_cast<char*>(str.c_str()), " ");`... seriously?

Comment: codereview.stackexchange.com may also be helpful to look at this code.

Comment: @Mat What's your suggestion? Seriously.

Comment: Has your friend done any profiling that revealed that simply looping over the characters of the string (either using indices or iterators) is too inefficient?

Comment: @Mat, I wonder if he realizes that `strtok` will mutilate his string into unusability..

Comment: @Blindly: that's exactly what I had in mind. @karlphillip: `strtok` **modifies** it's first argument if it finds the token. That's why it doesn't take a `const char*` and why your `const_cast` is precisely the wrong thing to do.

Comment: @Mat I'm aware that it destroys the buffer, thank you. Who voted -1? Is this not a decent question?

Comment: I only remember, when I used strtok once, it was slow as hell and was much slower than a custom little for loop.

Comment: update1: http://codepad.org/jo0vIk3G (requires `x` to be null-terminated).

Comment: if you are lucky, perhaps this is faster: http://codepad.org/9RSvBGdb

Comment: That's interesting. You should add it as an answer.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

```
if(str.find_first_not_of(' ') != std::string::npos)
{
    // There's a non-space.
}
```

Comment: +1 Great, a standard library function! (Was just about to post that one.)

Comment: Depending on the actual purpose, this may need to be an `isspace()` rather than a hardcoded `' '`

Comment: @peterchen To emulate [isspace()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/isspace/) you can send a string as parameter, e.g. `str.find_first_not_of(" \t\n\v\f\r") != std::string::npos` to ignore spaces, tabs, newlines, vertical tabs, feeds and carriage returns.

Comment: @N.N.: that probably works for all practical purposes (especially when talking embedded), but I'd expect these to be considered spaces, too: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_(punctuation)#Spaces_in_Unicode

Comment: @peterchen I tried to replace ' ' with isspace() in Mark B's code but I get "too few arguments to isspace(int)".

Comment: Optimized and shorter best approach :)

Comment: Refer to STL at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_last_not_of/ as well.

Answer (score 71):

In C++11, the `all_of` algorithm can be employed:

```
// Check if s consists only of whitespaces
bool whiteSpacesOnly = std::all_of(s.begin(),s.end(),isspace);
```

Comment: On non-C++11 compilers you can use `boost::algorithm::all_of()` (which falls back to `std::all_of()` on C++11 compilers).

Comment: If gcc gives you the following error: "template argument deduction/substitution failed: couldn't deduce template parameter '_Predicate'" - see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21578544/stdremove-if-and-stdisspace-compile-time-error

Comment: @Sundae there are two isspace() functions, the one from <cctype> is what we need here, while the other from <locale> is not. The way to resolve it is to use ::isspace as the predicate.

Comment: This may crash if string is in unicode, prefer accepted answer.

Answer (score 20):

Why so much work, so much typing?

```
bool has_only_spaces(const std::string& str) {
   return str.find_first_not_of (' ') == str.npos;
}
```

Comment: I like separating this into its own function so what you're doing is immediately clear when you say something like `if (has_only_spaces (str)) { ... }`

Comment: A little nit picky, but the code snippet in this Answer lacks an opening parantheses thus causing a syntax error.  Easy fix for the person using this snippet, but just pointing it out.  Great question for acting as a catalyst for great responses!!!

Answer (score 7):

Wouldn't it be easier to do:

```
bool has_only_spaces(const std::string &str)
{
    for (std::string::const_iterator it = str.begin(); it != str.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (*it != ' ') return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This has the advantage of returning early as soon as a non-space character is found, so it will be marginally more efficient than solutions that examine the whole string.

Comment: +1 Like it. It does the minimal necessary amount of work as long as you want to remain portable. Worst case you'll have to look at everything, but you can stop as soon as you know it's over. (I'd just sprinkle a lot of `const`s over this.)

Comment: The only possible low-level optimisation I could think of would be to compare in chunks of register width, e.g. 4 byte at a time on x86, and compare against 0x20202020. But that's insane.

Answer (score 5):

To check if string has only whitespace in c++11:

```
bool is_whitespace(const std::string& s) {
  return std::all_of(s.begin(), s.end(), isspace);
}
```

in pre-c++11:

```
bool is_whitespace(const std::string& s) {
  for (std::string::const_iterator it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ++it) {
    if (!isspace(*it)) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: I believe the line: `return std::all_of(s.begin(), s.end(), isspace);` is, as far as I know, undefined behaviour. 
Prefer: `std::all_of(s.begin(), s.end(), [](unsigned char c){ return std::isspace(c); });`

Comment: @ViralTaco_ why is that undefined behavior?

Comment: @jrh Two reasons: 
1. Passing the address of a standard library function (In this case `std::isspace` to `std::all_of`
2. [quote] the behavior of std::isspace is undefined if the argument's value is neither representable as unsigned char nor equal to EOF. To use these functions safely with plain chars (or signed chars), the argument should first be converted to unsigned char [/quote] [confer (cppreferecence)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace)

Answer (score 4):

Here's one that only uses STL (Requires C++11)

```
inline bool isBlank(const std::string& s)
{
    return std::all_of(s.cbegin(),s.cend(),[](char c) { return std::isspace(c); });
}
```

It relies on fact that if string is empty (begin = end) std::all_of also returns true

Here is a small test program: http://cpp.sh/2tx6

Answer (score 2):

Using strtok like that is bad style! strtok *modifies* the buffer it tokenizes (it replaces the delimiter chars with \0).

Here's a non modifying version.

```
const char* p = str.c_str();
while(*p == ' ') ++p;
return *p != 0;
```

It can be optimized even further, if you iterate through it in machine word chunks. To be portable, you would also have to take alignment into consideration.

Comment: I'm aware that `strtok()` destroys the buffer. And thank you for the answer.

Comment: No need for two tests. `while (*p == ' ') ++p;` will work just as well here.

Answer (score 1):

it's highly unlikely you'll beat a compiler optimized naive algorithm for this, e.g.

```
string::iterator it(str.begin()), end(str.end())    
for(; it != end && *it == ' '; ++it);
return it == end;
```

EDIT: Actually - there is a quicker way (depending on size of string and memory available)..

```
std::string ns(str.size(), ' '); 
return ns == str;
```

EDIT: actually above is not quick.. it's daft... stick with the naive implementation, the optimizer will be all over that...

EDIT AGAIN: dammit, I guess it's better to look at the functions in `std::string`

```
return str.find_first_not_of(' ') == string::npos;
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not approve of you const_casting above and using strtok.

A std::string can contain embedded nulls but let's assume it will be all ASCII 32 characters before you hit the NULL terminator.

One way you can approach this is with a simple loop, and I will assume const char *.

```
bool all_spaces( const char * v )
{
   for ( ; *v; ++v )
   {
      if( *v != ' ' )
          return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

For larger strings, you can check word-at-a-time until you reach the last word, and then assume the 32-bit word (say) will be 0x20202020 which may be faster.

Comment: Be careful when checking words at a time. The start of the string may necessarily not be on a word boundary. On many architectures it will generate a fault, on others it will degrade performance significantly.

Comment: If the start of the string was allocated with malloc or new then it will always be on a word boundary, as it happens. You cannot guarantee it in general with a std::string as there is no guarantee that the data was allocated that way even if you use your own custom allocator as some string implementations have an internal buffer. Obviously if you do word-at-a-time checking you do the necessary byte-at-a-time checks at both the start and the end of the string

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
return std::find_if(
            str.begin(), str.end(),
            std::bind2nd( std::not_equal_to<char>(), ' ' ) )
    == str.end();
```

If you're interested in white space, and not just the space character,
then the best thing to do is to define a predicate, and use it:

```
struct IsNotSpace
{
    bool operator()( char ch ) const
    {
        return ! ::is_space( static_cast<unsigned char>( ch ) );
    }
};
```

If you're doing any text processing at all, a collection of such simple
predicates will be invaluable (and they're easy to generate
automatically from the list of functions in `<ctype.h>`).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in a programming assignment, and here is one other solution I came up with after reviewing others. here I simply create a new sentence without the new spaces. If there are double spaces I simply overlook them.

string sentence;
string newsent; //reconstruct new sentence
string dbl = "  ";

```
getline(cin, sentence);

int len = sentence.length();

for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){

//if there are multiple whitespaces, this loop will iterate until there are none, then go back one.
    if (isspace(sentence[i]) && isspace(sentence[i+1])) {do{ 
        i++;
    }while (isspace(sentence[i])); i--;} //here, you have to dial back one to maintain at least one space.  
    
    
    newsent +=sentence[i];
}
```

cout << newsent << "\n";

Answer (score 0):

Hm...I'd do this:

```
for (auto i = str.begin(); i != str.end() ++i)
    if (!isspace(i))
       return false;
```

Pseudo-code, isspace is located in cctype for C++.

Edit: Thanks to James for pointing out that isspace has undefined behavior on signed chars.

Comment: `auto` is C++0x. The OP has not stated that this is used. Please, unless the question is tagged C++0x, don't just use stuff that is not even official yet. At least mention it in your answer, so that others are not confused.

Comment: That's why I said it was pseudo code. I've never iterated through strings like this and I don't know the "correct" types, even if that sounds a bit silly.

Comment: Also, using the `isspace` in `<ctype.h>` on a `char` is undefined behavior.  You have to cast the `char` to `unsigned char` first.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `CString`, you can do

```
CString myString = "    "; // All whitespace
if(myString.Trim().IsEmpty())
{
    // string is all whitespace
}
```

This has the benefit of trimming all newline, space and tab characters.